# iterate over a set and create a string containing HTML

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I have the following code that is used in the Image gallery generating program [Jalbum](http://jalbum.net) to generate all keywords used for the images in the gallery.

```
Set allKeywords = new HashSet();
for (AlbumObject ao : currentObjects) {
   XmpManager mgr = ao.getXmpManager();
   if (mgr != null) {
      allKeywords.addAll(mgr.getKeywordSet());
   }
}
//get the Iterator
Iterator itr = allKeywords.iterator(); 
while(itr.hasNext())
   out.println(itr.next());
```

My question is when out.print:

```
out.println(itr.next());
```

how can I add html to each individual keyword? I basically want to outprint:

```
<a href="#">keyword</a>
```

I am a newbie in this realm so please be gentle!

Comment: `out.println("<a href=\"#\">" + itr.next() + "</a>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
out.println("<a href=\"#\">" + itr.next() + "</a>");
```

If you want to call `iterator.next()` two times

```
out.println("<a href=\"#\" class=\"label list2\""
                + " data-filter=\"" + "." + itr.next() + "\">"
                + (itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : "") + "</a>");
```

For your requirement I hope mgr.getKeywordSet() returns string

```
  String str = itr.next();
  System.out.println("<a href=\"#\" class=\"label list2\""
                + " data-filter=\"" + "." + str + "\">" + str + "</a>");
```

Comment: Can itr.next() be used twice? I get an error when I try it. I want to do something like this to add a data attribute.   out.println("<a href=\"#\" class=\"label list2\"" + " data-filter=\"" + "." + itr.next() + "\">"  +  itr.next() + "</a>");

Comment: `hasNext()` check is important before calling `next()` otherwise it next method throws `NoSuchElementExecption` is there is no element and `next()` is called

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice and don't quite understand how I might do this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your edited code works except that if I have 7 keywords, it only shows 4 of them and the last one it doesn't show the text for the link. I am playing with the code you so kindly gave me but still no luck with my feeble mind.

Comment: Ok Now I guess I have got your requirement. Updating the answer.

Comment: Your being very generous with your time and I appreciate it! Unfortunatley I get this error:    Parse error at line 13, column 16.  Encountered: str

Details:
inline evaluation of: ``  Set allKeywords = new HashSet(); for (AlbumObject ao : currentObjects) {   Xmp . . . ''

Comment: Replace code given by me inside while(itr.hasNext()){ Code here }

Comment: Please let me know if it is not working I will be signing off soon.

Comment: I tried that earlier, forgot to mention and got this error:    Evaluation error on line 13:

Details:
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``  Set allKeywords = new HashSet(); for (AlbumObject ao : currentObjects) {   Xmp . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: next() on undefined variable or class name: iterator

Comment: I assumed that you will replace iterator by your declaration itr now updated the answer.